# Add STS reference not displaying in VS2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wif

I have already done the following. I have VS Express 2010 (trial) installed on my windows 7 machine.

1. Installed WIF 6.1 and WIF sdk 4.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451
2. Installed VS C++ express to get Visual Studio command prompt
3. Tried to execute C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /ResetAddin Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tools.VS.VSAddin.FederationAddin. This does not work as devenv does not exist on my setup
4. Added "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tools.VS.VSAddin.Addin" to my user profile as described @ http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2011/06/14/Add-STS-Reference-is-Missing-in-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx

Still on right click of webrole "Add STS reference does not display"

Question:
Does this option appear for VS 2010 Express (trial edition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VS 2010 Express, that option does not exist. All is not lost however as that is simply a shortcut to FedUtil.exe.

This is part of the WIF SDK which you have already installed.

On my PC, it installs at C:\Program Files\Windows Identity Foundation SDK\v4.0.

Run that, point to the location of your web.config and follow the steps.

Comment: whew! The missing link. Much appreciated. Thank you