# Implementing SSO using Visual studio 2010 trial edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, single-sign-on, wif

I am trying to implement SSO using VS2010 (express). I just realized that the "STS reference" link is missing because WIF SDK is not implemented for VS2010 express according to this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vssetup/thread/4402cf81-f448-4311-8b8f-9a14a037b910.

Please see link below for my efforts to display STS link in VS2010 express

[Add STS reference not displaying in VS2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632361/add-sts-reference-not-displaying-in-vs2010-express)

Is there any other trial edition i can use for SSO implementation? How about VS 2010 professional?

Thanks 
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VS 2010 Express, that option does not exist. All is not lost however as that is simply a shortcut to FedUtil.exe.

This is part of the WIF SDK which you have already installed.

On my PC, it installs at C:\Program Files\Windows Identity Foundation SDK\v4.0.

Run that, point to the location of your web.config and follow the steps.